# best practice to send fancy email in ASP.NET & MVC

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-mvc-3, sendmail

HI,

I want to send a very fancy email to users.
thats look and feel is same as a web page.

one very bad way to use StringBuilder and append text in it.

but i am in search of a best practice solution. where the page is easy to redesign.

I need solution for both ASP.NET & MVC.

any idea.

thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC, I've been enjoying [ActionMailer.Net](https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/wiki/Home).

Answer (score 7):

You could try [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) or [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) both are available via NuGet and both allow you to send emails rendered from MVC Views.

Andrew Davey done a good video presentation on [Generating email with view engines using Postal](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Andrew-Davey-Going-Postal-Generating-email-with-View-Engines) at mvcConf2.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by writing your email template in a separate file (will be good for redesign if it is an HTML file), and then read this file like reading any file and fill it with variables, then use the result as a string to send in an email.

Comment: @Saboor, yes, I agreed, you can also embed images in email through asp.net email. More specific here http://www.mikepope.com/blog/DisplayBlog.aspx?permalink=1264

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing that is by using T4 Templates to compile all of the email templates in the separate assembly.

I blogged about that approach http://asmiki.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/using-t4-templates-for-compiling-net-email-templates/